# Notification disappears when app is closed

Tags: android, notifications

I have a timer in my app and I keep it running by service and show notification.

But several of users reports:

"When I close the app, notification disappears."

And when notification is gone, timer doesn't work.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your timer runs in some activity, so when you close the app, the code stops. You will need to create a service where you need to put the timer, so when the users close the app, the service will still run your code. Also you will need a broadcast receiver to handle the service into notifications.